# Истинный альфа-блендинг в webgl

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

По интернету гуляет стандартный способ

```
gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA
```

Или же

```
gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA
```

для предумноженных изображений.
Он идеален для наложения прозрачных текстур на непрозрачный фон.

Но что делать если мне нужно наложить текстуру с прозрачностью на фон с прозрачностью?
Нашел в википедии формулу (картинка). Как я понимаю, через blendfunc её никак не сделать.. или сделать?

[image: alpha blending]

Зачем мне это?
Хочу создать что-то типо рисовалки. Нужно отрисовать на canvas штрих кисти с учетом прозрачности как фона, так и самой кисти.

Как вариант: использовать два фреймбуффера и отрисовывать сначала сам canvas на один из них, а потом уже оба смешивать на canvas. Но такие костыли делать неохота.
Есть ли способ сделать нормальное смешивание за одну отрисовку?

Comment: На сколько я помню, к сожалению автоматическиое смешивание цвета фрагментов и framebuffer-а переопределить, кроме как через blendfunc - никак нельзя. :(